# POST a Speex/Flac file to Google Voice Search API via Java

Tags: c#, java, http-post, voice-recognition

I am trying to build an Java Application ,which connects to the Google Voice Search API.
I have developed a C# programm, which is working fine.

C#:

```
try
{
   FileStream FS_Audiofile = new FileStream("temp.flac", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   BinaryReader BR_Audiofile = new BinaryReader(FS_Audiofile);
   byte[] BA_AudioFile = BR_Audiofile.ReadBytes((Int32)FS_Audiofile.Length);
   FS_Audiofile.Close();
   BR_Audiofile.Close();

   HttpWebRequest _HWR_SpeechToText = null;

   _HWR_SpeechToText = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=de-DE&maxresults=1&pfilter=0");

   _HWR_SpeechToText.Method = "POST";
   _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=44100";
   _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentLength = BA_AudioFile.Length;
   _HWR_SpeechToText.GetRequestStream().Write(BA_AudioFile, 0, BA_AudioFile.Length);

   HttpWebResponse HWR_Response = (HttpWebResponse)_HWR_SpeechToText.GetResponse();
   if (HWR_Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
      StreamReader SR_Response = new StreamReader(HWR_Response.GetResponseStream());
   }

}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

And here the Code Java, which doesn't work:

```
RandomAccessFile accessFile = new RandomAccessFile("temp.flac", "r");
byte[] bs = new byte[(int)accessFile.length()];
accessFile.read(bs);

        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            URL url = new URL("http", "www.google.com", "/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=de-DE&maxresults=1&pfilter=0");
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            int contentLength = bs.length;

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
            httpURLConnection.setUseCaches (false);

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-flac; rate=44100");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(contentLength));

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.write(bs);
            dataOutputStream.flush();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
            System.out.println(scanner.toString());

        }
        catch ( Exception e)
        {
           System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
```

I am getting the exception "java.io.IOException: Error writing to server".

Does anyone see, which kind of error I am doing?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Thx and Regards
Linoge

Comment: *building libastral.so failed...* define `doesn't work`. print out any exception you're getting or any errors you receive.

Comment: The exception message is "Error writing to server"

Comment: why don't you just use regular URL constructor that accepts whole url string?

Comment: Okay, but how do I do that? I am not familiar with URL constructors.

Comment: `new URL("http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=de-DE&maxresults=1&pfilter=0")`

Comment: I have tried that and I get the same error. "java.io.IOException: Error writing to server"

Comment: try using a smaller file

Comment: is just 901Kb and I have tried 5KB, both with the same result. The funny thing is the C# code it is working perfectly. But in need java in order to run this on a linux system.

Comment: Found the issue, the above code works, but in Java you have to specify the procy server as well, if you use one. Like in my case I use a proxy. the additional code is: `Properties properties = System.getProperties();
  properties.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "your.proxy.com");
  properties.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1234"); ` In C# I didn't have to do that.

Comment: where did you add the Google voice key?